# way to include own functions independent of theme

Tags: theme-development, wp-enqueue-script

I know how to include my own functions by writing them into the theme's `functions.php` and enqueuing them, or by including a php file containing all that in `functions.php`.

But that is always bound to the used theme. If I switch to another theme, I always have to copy that code to the new theme's `functions.php`

Is there any way around that - a place/file where I can define and enqueue scripts that remain valid across all themes? (without loosing it when WP is updated)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not quite simple (as copying and pasting into new functions.php :D), but you can create a plugin that will load this every time.

A (very) good and simple guide [can be found here](https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/create-wordpress-plugin/).

### Addition by Original Poster (johannes)

I created a plugin for that:

1. I created a simple php file and put it into `wp-content/plugins`. It looks basically like this (i.e. it contains the plugin name, description, author etc. and the function I want to use in my site across all themes):

   ```
   <?php
   /**
    * Plugin Name: Function-Includer
    * Plugin URI: my URI
    * Description: my description
    * Version: 1.0
    * Author: johannes
    * Author URI: my URI
    */

   [... code of my function ...]

   ?>
   ```
2. Then I went into the WP admin backend, to the plugin page, where that plugin is listed as "Function-Includer" and activated it.
3. Done - the function is available everywhere in my site now.

Comment: May you please elaborate on how this guide would help?

Comment: Wow, this wasn't even all that hard in my case - first I hesitated, but then I managed creating that plugin in a few minutes, and it works :-)

Comment: Detailing what you did as an answer or an edit to the accepted answer would improve this Q&A for others.

Comment: @AndyMacaulay-Brook okay, I just did that

Comment: do you mind sharing the code? Without complete code I don't see how this answer can help anybody!!

Comment: @Tara It can be any function. In my case it's a very simple function that returns the full username when given only the user ID, which I use in a "PODS template" (a proprietary template format of that plugin in order to display/style custom posts which allows the use of WP functions in conjunction with its own "Magic Tags").

Comment: Glad you made it Pat ;)